# ListSecrets on Azure Vault using an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

How do I get a secret from an azure Vault using an ARM template?

My template:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "referenceOutput": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[listSecrets(resourceId('my-resource-group', 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', 'myKeyVault','mySecret'), '2016-10-01')]"
        }
    }
}
```

And then run with:

```
az group deployment create -g some-rg --template-file ./arm.json
```

Error:

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: f76de3f2-a9ff-427c-9ae0-b7b24c3fde5d. {
  "error": {    "code": "BadRequest",    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html P

....

<h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>\r\n  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</ht
ml>\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing that with an ARM Template, but you can refecence secrets in an ARM Template to pass those as values.

```
"password": {
    "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
            "id": "vaultId"
        },
        "secretName": "secretName"
    }
}
```

But you have to know that this expression cannot be used directly in the template. You can use this in the parameters file and\or when invoking a nested template.

Also, you can use similar expressions for some of the properties of some of the resources (like VM password)